# How to access state value on page refresh in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I am implementing time tracker in my project. When I start my tracker then I stored this tracker value into state and when pausing this tracker then change that value into the state. But when I refresh the page I am not getting last updated state value. So how can I get state value on page refresh?

```
const React = require("react");
const ms = require("pretty-ms");

class TaskTimer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: 0,
      isOn: false,
      start: 0
    };
    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this);
    this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
  }

  startTimer() {
    this.setState({
      isOn: true,
      time: this.state.time,
      start: Date.now() - this.state.time
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(
      () =>
        this.setState({
          time: Date.now() - this.state.start
        }),
      1
    );
  }
  stopTimer() {
    this.setState({ isOn: false });
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
  resetTimer() {
    this.setState({ time: 0, isOn: false });
  }
  render() {
    let start =
      this.state.time == 0 ? (
        <button onClick={this.startTimer}>start</button>
      ) : null;
    let stop =
      this.state.time == 0 || !this.state.isOn ? null : (
        <button onClick={this.stopTimer}>stop</button>
      );
    let resume =
      this.state.time == 0 || this.state.isOn ? null : (
        <button onClick={this.startTimer}>resume</button>
      );
    let reset =
      this.state.time == 0 || this.state.isOn ? null : (
        <button onClick={this.resetTimer}>reset</button>
      );
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>timer: {ms(this.state.time)}</h3>
        {start}
        {resume}
        {stop}
        {reset}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
module.exports = TaskTimer;
```

Anyone please suggest me for how to get state value on page refresh?

Answer (score 3):

if you want your state to persist after refresh, then you would need to store the state in localStorage in `componentWillUnmount` and then reset the state to what it used to be in `componentDidMount`. That is

```
componentDidMount() {
  const stateObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("state"));
  this.setState(stateObject); 
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(this.state));
}
```

This can have unexpected results however in case the componentWillUnmount isn't able to be called during refresh. So a more robust (but less performant) method would be to update the state to localStorage each time you update your state. This can be done by putting the code in `componentDidUpdate`.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevState != this.state) {
    localStorage.setItem("state", this.state);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After some research I found the event `beforeunload` which could work in a fairly performant way.

```
  onUnload = (event) => {
    localStorage.setItem("state", JSON.stringify(this.state)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.onUnload)
  }
```

However, keep in mind that onbeforeunload is not properly implemented in some browsers (Safari in iOS for example). So you might face some issues with respect to that. This is the compatibility list for the event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility.

Comment: I am not storing state value to local storage because of my state value change in every second. The main problem is to when timer running and I am refreshing page at that time state value reinitialize with zero. So how can I get last state value of timer when I am refreshing a page.

Comment: From your code it looks like your state changes a thousand times a second. `setInterval` takes it's second argument in miliseconds.

Comment: Also, the only way to ensure that a particular value stays in scope after a refresh is to either store it in localStorage or to store is as a url parameter. However, that would mean that your URL would change every second, which can be very distracting for a user.

Comment: I think you could use a library called **lscache** (https://github.com/pamelafox/lscache). You can save the state value for a time and use it after.

Comment: @Pedrinhow Lscache stands for local storage cache..it&#39;s going to do the exact same thing I mentioned except that it would be abstracted behind a library

Comment: Please suggest me solution for how to prevent timer reinitialize with zero when refreshing a page because when we start a timer and refresh the page at that time timer value will reinitialize with zero and we can not get last timer value.

Comment: @Ankit updated the answer. This method should  work better than the ones mentioned above

Comment: @ManavM I tried this solution but in onUnload method, we can not get state value.

Comment: @Ankit try binding component context to it by adding `this.boundOnUnload = this.onUnload.bind(this);` to your constructor and then attach this bound function to the events instead.